# What is the script that is used in SQL Server Management Studio to rollback?

Tags: sql-server

How do I rollback the updates which are made in SQL Server Management Studio?

I updated a table using the normal update command.

Comment: i dont think this is possible if you have backup then restore this.

Comment: *Either* your transaction is still *active*, e.g. hasn't been committed or rolled back yet - then you can just use `ROLLBACK` and be done. But if your transaction has completed (e.g. your `UPDATE` statement is done, and is not inside an explicit transaction `BEGIN TRAN ...... UPDATE .....`, then you're out of luck - go get the most recent backup and restore it....

Comment: I am using SSMS it has some auto commit feature... So i am unable to rollback i guess. Neither am I able to create an setpoint in it.

Comment: Auto commit is when you use implicit transaction mode. by default, there is no transaction in SSMS, unless you explicitly start a transaction.. so you cannot do that. I think there is a way to read logs with some utility software and you need a DBA to do that. it is not easy. if the update is not important, it doesn't worht it

Comment: It works with the use of Transaction.

Answer (score 3):

If the update statement that you made is already done without `Begin Transaction`, There is no way to roll it back..

In case you want to do this in the future, you need to use Transaction:

```
BEGIN TRAN T1;
UPDATE table1 ...;


COMMIT TRAN T1;--To Commit
ROLLBACK TRAN T1;--To Rollback
```

Comment: Thanks Sufyan ! Will try this next time.